# Where to get past releases of arch linux

Tags: arch-linux

I am looking for past releases of arch linux preferably those with AIF (Arch Linux Installation Framework).Do arch linux maintain an archive of iso's of the past releases?.

Thanks.

Comment: hi again.  why the old version?  Anyhoo, try looking through the mirrors.  I didn't know you could get arch without AIF (i had to look up what it was).  I'm pretty sure all their ISOs use AIF.

Comment: @mcalex ["2012-07-22 AIF removed and replaced with simple install scripts"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch_Linux#Install_media_history)

Comment: You can ask in #archlinux on freenode, but AIF was broken and was removed for the install scripts to have a more easily customized install.

Answer (score 0):

You can download previous releases of Arch Linux here --> https://archive.archlinux.org/

More details on this can be found here --> https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_Linux_Archive